# delete a file using a child process in .net

Tags: .net, windows, child-process, filehandle

My app uses a file and tries to delete it after using it. However, due to a third party library, my app can't release the file handle of this file, hence can't delete the file, because the file is used by the process itself. I tried to call process.start() to start a separate process, whose only job is to delete the previously mentioned file. I am using .net 4.0. However, it seems the new process has inherited the file handle and can't delete the file either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you delete the file by hand while your app has it open?  You might find that no process can delete it.

Comment: Are you launching this new process and then exiting the current one, before it attempts the delete?

Comment: yes, my new process will check for the presence of the current one before it tries to delete the file.

Comment: It should not check for presence, it should wait for un-presence. Can you show us the code to achieve this deletion task?

Answer (score 0):

Why would a different process be able to delete a file that your own process can't delete? This is not how it works. If that was the case you could always circumvent access limitations by just starting a new process.

You *must* close the handle to delete the file.

If the library can't be made to properly close the handle you can start a child process that contains all the library work. After you're done you exit the child. The handle is closed as part of process cleanup.

Comment: This is not an access limitations issue. I am just trying to fix the issue that a file handle is not properly released. If I exit the current process, and then start the other process from command line, the other process has no problem delete the file, as the file handle was release when I exit the original process. What I am trying to do here is to automate this process by fire the file-deleting process from within the original process and then immediately exit the original process. The file-deleting process then waits until the original process exit to start deleting the file.

Comment: I understand. That will work. Handles are only inherited when explicitly specified. Probably, the delete operation was started before the parent exited. Communicate the parent PID to the child and make the child wait for exit before deleting.

Comment: it seems System.Diagnostic.Process.start() call will by default inherit file handle from the calling process, which is causing the problem. A solution is proposed by Sad Robot, and here is the link. [link](http://www.sadrobot.co.nz/2011/06/21/when-system-diagnostics-process-creates-a-process-it-inherits-inheritable-handles-from-the-parent-process/)

Comment: This handle inheriting issue only exists for handles explicitly marked for inheritance at creation time. If the library does that then yes you need a custom CreateProcess call. Are you sure the library explicitly marks the handle for inheritance? That is very rare.